# Android: Gridview Items and making changes to individual items

Tags: java, android, button, gridview, onclicklistener

I'm building an app similar to instagram just for training purposes and basically I have a list of images that I populate through a grid view adapter. In my XML file for 'single_list_item' I have defined a button to be added along with the image for each single item on the grid view list.

However, I want to be able to click on these buttons to 'place a like' on these images separately (similar to instagram's like system). In other words: a user could place a like on the first image and not like the rest of the images. I display a like using a different image resource.

> Images get populated by the grid view
>
> Each image has a Like button beneath it
>
> I click on a random like button belonging to a specific image
>
> that image should be selected as 'liked'

What I tried so far:

**My grid adapter:**

```
public class ProductGridInflator extends ArrayAdapter<Product>{

.......
.......

@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

View child = convertView;
        final RecordHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) ctx).getLayoutInflater(); 

    if (child == null) {            
      child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, parent, false);
      holder = new RecordHolder();
      holder.productName = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
      holder.image = (ImageView) child.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
      holder.heartButton = (ImageButton) child.findViewById(R.id.btnHeartLike);
      holder.heartButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v.isSelected()){
                    v.setSelected(false);
                } else {
                    holder.heartButton.setSelected(false);
                    v.setSelected(true);
                    }
                }
            });
            child.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (RecordHolder) child.getTag();
        }
    }
}
```

**And I'm selecting the appropriate image from a selector (Liked or unliked)**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/heart_clicked" android:state_selected="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/heart304"/>
    
    </selector>
```

However this code is misbehaving when I test it. When I click on the like button of a specific image list item, two or three other list item's like buttons get clicked as well. Is there a better way to get this done? Individual buttons for each list item?

Answer (score 0):

THe Problem is that you are reusing the onclicklisteners .. Remove this from your `getView`

```
holder.heartButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

And instead write in your activity

```
YouGridView.setOnItemClickListener
```

And add what you want to do when an item is clicked.

Comment: The problem is, I already have a OnItemClickListener for my gridview which takes the user to a different page. So when I click on an image the app takes the user to a different page to maximize and show the image.